# Nested Observables from nested http requests in Angular

Tags: ajax, angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

Here's what I intend to do.

- Request `https://reqres.in/api/users/2`
- Which sends a response as follows.

  ```
  {
    "data": {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Janet",
      "last_name": "Weaver",
      "avatar":
        "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
    }
  }
  ```

  - Now, I wanna grab the avatar url and make another request, which gives me the image binary.
  - At the end of this, what I want as output is an Observable that gives me this data.

    ```
    {
      "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Janet",
        "last_name": "Weaver",
        "avatar":
          "BINARY_GIBBERISH HERE"
      }
    }
    ```

### Here's how I approached but can't finish it.

```
this.http
  .get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2')
  .switchMap(a => {
    const image$ = this.http.get(a.json().data.avatar);
    const data = Observable.of(a.json().data);
    // Do something here to combine.
  })
  .subscribe(a => {
    // get data here.
  });
}
```

Basically, is there any way to have a structure like this,

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Janet",
    "last_name": "Weaver",
    "avatar": [Observable from this.http.get]
  }
}
```

Which then gets resolved to my final data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `switchMap` for this and use `concatMap` or `mergeMap` instead:

```
this.http
  .get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2')
  .concatMap(a => {
    const data = a.json().data;
    const image$ = this.http.get(data.avatar);

    return image$.map(imageData => {
      data.avatar = imageData;
      return data;
    });
  })
  .subscribe(a => {
    // get data here.
  });
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much :)